# Is it possible to call a stored procedure using NHibernate which returns a custom object instead of domain object?

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, nhibernate-mapping

I have several stored procedures that don't return the domain objects (i.e; objects which have corresponding sql table mapping in hbm files); but return the custom objects instead.

I want to call these stored procedures using NHibernate and fill my custom objects with the output automatically, instead of filling them mannually as I would do if I use a SqlDataReader.

An example shall be highly appreciated.

BTW: I use nhibernate 3.2 new feature mapping by code.

Comment: I've encountered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883855/nhibernate-how-to-map-to-a-class-that-has-no-table-for-custom-sql-queries. But, it has hbm mapping. Now, trying to do it in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10513319/1236044 )

It uses CreateSQLQuery. You may try replacing the `select...` with `Exec MyStoredProc`

The key point is having your select or stored procedure return columns with the same name as the properties of the DTO you are trying to populate.

```
public class YourDto
{
    public int YourDtoId { get; set; }
    public string YourDtoTitle { get; set; }
}

then

var result = yourNhSession
    .CreateSQLQuery("select yourColumn1 as YourDtoId, yourColumn2 as YourDtoTitle from YOUR_TABLE")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<YourDto>())
    .List<YourDto>();
```