# Is it possible to call the stored procedure using NHibernate and fill a DataTable?

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, datatable

I already know how we call a stored procedure using NHibernate and fill a DTO (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750969/is-it-possible-to-call-a-stored-procedure-using-nhibernate-which-returns-a-custo)).

But, I was wondering if its possible somehow to fill a DataTable using the same concept of ResultTransformer in NHibernate or is there any other recommended approach?

I'd prefer using the concept of ResultTransformer in NHibernate. But, I don't know whether its possible and how. Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: It seems someone tried it with some success :-) http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/10/07/load-a-strongly-typed-dataset-from-a-stored-with-nhibernate/

Comment: @jbl, +1 for the reference, I ve used the concept and put the solution as answer :-). Please have a look at it.

Comment: NHibernate is nothing but noise in this scenario. Just get the connection from it (if you want) and use a DataAdapter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came up with the following solution using the concept of ResultTransformer described [here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/10/07/load-a-strongly-typed-dataset-from-a-stored-with-nhibernate/):

```
  public class DataTableResultTransformer : IResultTransformer
  {
    private DataTable dataTable;

    public IList TransformList(IList collection)
    {
      var rows = collection.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
      rows.ForEach(dataRow => dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow));
      return new List<DataTable> { dataTable };
    }

    public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
    {
      //Create the table schema based on aliases if its not already done
      CreateDataTable(aliases);

      //Create and Fill DataRow
      return FillDataRow(tuple, aliases);
    }

    private DataRow FillDataRow(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
    {
      DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
      aliases.ToList().ForEach(alias =>
                                 {
                                   dataRow[alias] = tuple[Array.FindIndex(aliases, colName => colName == alias)];
                                 });
      return dataRow;
    }

    private void CreateDataTable(IEnumerable<string> aliases)
    {
      if (dataTable == null)
      {
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        aliases.ToList().ForEach(alias => dataTable.Columns.Add(alias));
      }
    }
  }
```

And use it as following:

```
    using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
      var sqlQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMER");
      var transformedQuery = sqlQuery.SetResultTransformer(new DataTableResultTransformer());
      return transformedQuery.List().Single();
    }
```

I have just created a custom ResultTransformer and use it in my sql query to transform the result of the query based on my logic in the DataTableResultTransformer.

The TransformTupple method is called for each item in the result set. The tuple contains the data where as the aliases contain the names for the data. So, we have almost everything to build and fill our DataTable. Once all the items of the result set have been transformed by the TransformTupple method then the TransformList method is called at the end. The collection parameter contains all items that we transformed into DataRow in TransformTupple method. So, here we can easily fill our DataTable with the DataRows and return.

Hope its helpful for others dealing with same kind of scenario.

Comment: This doesn't actually work because each column will be converted into a `string`. You need to setup the `DataTable` columns with the correct data types, which you can't do if there are any nulls in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Updated example that take column data types into account

```
[SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1001")]
public class DataTableResultTransformer : IResultTransformer
{
    readonly Type?[] m_DataTypeOverrides = Array.Empty<Type?>();
    readonly DataTable m_DataTable = new DataTable();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DataTableResultTransformer"/> class.
    ///
    /// Only use this constructor if none of the columns are nullable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Warning: If a field is NULL in the first row, that entire column will be cast as a String.</remarks>
    public DataTableResultTransformer()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DataTableResultTransformer"/> class.
    ///
    /// 1. If dataTypeOverrides for a given column is not null, it is used.
    /// 2. If the field is not null for the first row, then that field's data type if used.
    /// 3. If both the dataTypeOverride and the field in the first row are null, the column's data type is String.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataTypeOverrides">The expected data types.</param>
    public DataTableResultTransformer(params Type?[] dataTypeOverrides)
    {
        m_DataTypeOverrides = dataTypeOverrides;
    }

    public IList TransformList(IList collection)
    {
        return new List<DataTable> { m_DataTable };
    }

    public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
    {
        if (tuple == null || tuple.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(tuple)} is null or empty.", nameof(tuple));

        if (aliases == null || aliases.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(aliases)} is null or empty.", nameof(aliases));

        if (m_DataTable.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            //Create the DataTable if this is the first row
            for (var i = 0; i < aliases.Length; i++)
            {
                var col = m_DataTable.Columns.Add(aliases[i]);
                if (i < m_DataTypeOverrides.Length && m_DataTypeOverrides[i] != null)
                    col.DataType = m_DataTypeOverrides[i];
                else if (tuple[i] != null && tuple[i] != DBNull.Value)
                    col.DataType = tuple[i].GetType();
            }
        }

        return m_DataTable.Rows.Add(tuple);
    }
}
```