# Dynamically map nhibernate native result to DataSet

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

For reporting scenarios, specially for large records (+millions records) I decided to bypass the nhibernate object mapping! and directly map to DataSet!

Here is the algorithm

```
ICriteria criteria = _session.CreateCriteria(entityType);
// Add some filters and paging to criteria 

ISQLQuery sql = GetGeneratedSql(criteria); // According to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704462/how-can-i-have-nhibernate-only-generate-the-sql-without-executing-it/10710451#10710451)

IList<object[]> data = sql.List<object[]>();
```

I didn't figure out how to find the columns that nhibernate used to build the SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a `DataSet` can use this transformer:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109744/1486443)

Its transform to a `DataTable` but is easy to handle it.