# Map custom query to object in nHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Please take a look at this example:

([Is it possible to call a stored procedure using NHibernate which returns a custom object instead of domain object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750969/is-it-possible-to-call-a-stored-procedure-using-nhibernate-which-returns-a-custo))

Suppose that my structure have this definition:

```
public class YourDto
{
    public int YourDtoId { get; set; }
    public string YourDtoTitle { get; set; }
    public List<YourDtoBook> YourDtoList { get; set; }
}
```

And now let's assume that I have a single query like this:

```
select yourColumn1 as YourDtoId, yourColumn2 as YourDtoTitle,
yourColumn3 as YourDtoList from YOUR_TABLE
```

The result of this query is something like this:

```
YourDtoId| YourDtoTitle| YourDtoList
_____________________________________
1        |Jeff         | book1
1        |Jeff         | book2
2        |Kurt         | book3
2        |Kurt         | book4
```

What do I do to map these entities correctly? (i.e. two objects with two lists each one)

Comment: You may need to issue two separate queries, one to get the "root" items, and then another to get the related lists

Answer (score 0):

Using QueryOver with mapped classes use Fetch Eager.

Directly to DTOs maybe using GroupBy:

```
var result = yourNhSession.CreateSQLQuery(@"
                select yourColumn1 as YourDtoId, yourColumn2 as YourDtoTitle,
                yourColumn3 as YourDtoList from YOUR_TABLE")
                .List<object[]>()
                .GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    YourDtoId = (int) x[0],
                    YourDtoTitle = (string) x[1]
                })
                .Select(x => new YourDto
                {
                    YourDtoId = x.Key.YourDtoId,
                    YourDtoTitle = x.Key.YourDtoTitle,
                    YourDtoList = x.Select(y => new YourDtoBook
                    {
                        Name = (string)y[2]
                    }).ToList()
                });

    public class YourDto
    {
        public int YourDtoId { get; set; }
        public string YourDtoTitle { get; set; }
        public List<YourDtoBook> YourDtoList { get; set; }
    }

    public class YourDtoBook
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```